# CSS / Bootstrap Display issues and errors

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4

OK, I have some PHP code for a Star Wars page that I am designing for a university course, and I am running into issues that I cannot seem to resolve.  I'm using templates, and I have a basic design that I will then be using connecting to MySQL to actually populate and repeat the images and such.

The issues that I have so far.Header:  No matter what I do, I cannot get the header to fix in place.  The footer is fixed without issue.  And the above font works as well.

Cards:  I'm using cards to display the images and names.  They are all fixed size, and I cannot see any way to change that.  I have searched and I cannot see any way to change that.

Finally, there is an error on the page that I cannot see for the life of me why it is there!

```
"Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\SWDB\controllers\characterChoose.php:2
 Stack trace:
 #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SWDB\index.php(6): require_once()
 #1 {main}
 thrown inC:\xampp\htdocs\SWDB\controllers\characterChoose.php
 on line 2"
```

Code 1 :  main template page (main.tpl)

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet'>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light"
        <a class="navbar-brand-left">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7vJj2z4/logo-small.png" class="float-left" alt="">
        <a class="navbar-brand-centre">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/xHWc1tj/Jedi-Mind-Reader-Logo-Small.png" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="">
        <a class="navbar-brand-right">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7vJj2z4/logo-small.png" class="float-right" alt="">
        </a>
      </a>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
{block name="body"}
<p>Some Text And Stuff</p>
{/block}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Orbitron;

}

.footer a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.footer a:hover {
  background: red;
  color: black;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="footer">
  <a>© S199289 2020 Copyright</a>
  <a href="mailto:S199289@uos.ac.uk?subject=Jedi-Mind-Reader">Contact us here for any questions</a>
  <a href="http://www.starwars.com">Star Wars Website</a>
</div>
</body>
</style>
</html>
```

Code 2:  CSS style sheet

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Heroic Features (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/heroic-features)
 * Copyright 2013-2019 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-heroic-features/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */


* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  background:url("https://i.ibb.co/zb9LVC1/Stars-background.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.css-selector {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif ! important;
  color: yellow ! important;
}

.button {
    width: 6em;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.header, .footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;


}

.footer {
   color: white;
}

.header {
  color: yellow;
}

.header, .footer a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header, .footer a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header, .footer a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}

.header, .footer a.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
}

.header-right, .footer-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header, .footer a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .header-right, .footer-right {
    float: none;
  }
  .background-image{
    margin:0;
      padding:0;
      background:url("https://i.ibb.co/zb9LVC1/Stars-background.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  }
}
}
```

Code 3:  page I'm trying to get to work.

```
{extends file="layouts/main.tpl"}
{block name="body"}
<div class = "text-center">
  <div class = "css-selector"
<h1 class="custom"> Choose Your Character!</h1>
<p class="custom">Scroll through the characters below.  Once you have chosen, click on "Use The Force" to start!"
</div>
<div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
    <div class="text-center gallery">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/image_21d0b16d.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1280%2C871"
    alt="Luke Skywalker">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card css-selector bg-dark"
      <h5 class="card-title">Luke Skywalker</h5>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="text-center gallery">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/open-uri20150608-27674-t1uk0r_874e197a.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C666%2C900"
    alt="Boba Fett">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card css-selector bg-dark">
      <h5 class="card-title">Boba Fett</h5>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="text-center gallery">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/open-uri20150608-27674-yyyjud_fa69f3b7.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1280%2C720"
    alt="Leia Organa">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card css-selector bg-dark">
      <h5 class="card-title">Leia Organa</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
{/block}
```

Comment: Would be easier for other people to help if you can create a working code snippet that can be run and previewd for example at jsfillde.

Comment: I have tried to do that, but it's not allowing me to use the 2 template files and the 1 CSS file.  But, for what it is worth.  https://jsfiddle.net/Steevi93/p4n8hf3r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fu4976pd/2/). In that, I added your bits from your questions to the html to complete how the site looks. I corrected also some tags and added bootstrap stylesheet link.

---

There are some unclosed tags in your code, for example in `main.tpl`:

```
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <! –– Here ––>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light"
        <a class="navbar-brand-left">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7vJj2z4/logo-small.png" class="float-left" alt="">
        <a class="navbar-brand-centre">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/xHWc1tj/Jedi-Mind-Reader-Logo-Small.png" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="">
        <a class="navbar-brand-right">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/7vJj2z4/logo-small.png" class="float-right" alt="">
        </a>
      </a>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Also you close `<header>` with `</head>` instead of `</header>`:

```
...
</head>
<body>

<div class="footer">
  <a>© S199289 2020 Copyright</a>
...
```

I suggest you use a code editor that has prettifier or html syntax check, for example vscode.

---

> Header: No matter what I do, I cannot get the header to fix in place.
>   The footer is fixed without issue. And the above font works as well.

I don't see that you have any css or any class name for the header to fix the its position. You can try adding this:

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed !important; //important to override bootstrap
  z-index:99;

}
```

---

> Cards: I'm using cards to display the images and names. They are all fixed size, and I cannot see any way to change that. I have searched and I cannot see any way to change that.

Depends on how you want to change their size, you can override their css to fit what you want or you read more about bootstrap 4 cards sizing from here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#sizing

About the Error that you have with your php, you need to check the file that the site informs you about: characterChoose.php in line 2. Maybe you can post that file here so people can help. There's something wrong with how you declare the class name.

---

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.  I'd spent so long staring at the code that I was losing the will to live.  I've got everything working now EXCEPT for the cards, which I will follow your advice now!